# docker-compose ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<scalar>'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

getting error :

```
admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog/kafka/k8s1$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<scalar>'
  in "./docker-compose.yaml", line 36, column 1
```

admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog/kafka/k8s1$ cat docker-compose.yaml

```
FROM openjdk:8u151-jre-alpine

ARG kafka_version=1.1.0
ARG scala_version=2.12
ARG glibc_version=2.27-r0

MAINTAINER wurstmeister

ENV KAFKA_VERSION=$kafka_version \
    SCALA_VERSION=$scala_version \
    KAFKA_HOME=/opt/kafka \
    GLIBC_VERSION=$glibc_version

ENV PATH=${PATH}:${KAFKA_HOME}/bin

COPY download-kafka.sh start-kafka.sh broker-list.sh create-topics.sh /tmp/

RUN apk add --no-cache bash curl jq docker \
 && mkdir /opt \
 && chmod a+x /tmp/*.sh \
 && mv /tmp/start-kafka.sh /tmp/broker-list.sh /tmp/create-topics.sh /usr/bin \
 && sync && /tmp/download-kafka.sh \
 && tar xfz /tmp/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt \
 && rm /tmp/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz \
 && ln -s /opt/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION} /opt/kafka \
 && rm /tmp/* \
 && wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
 && apk add --no-cache --allow-untrusted glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
 && rm glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk

COPY overrides /opt/overrides

VOLUME ["/kafka"]

# Use "exec" form so that it runs as PID 1 (useful for graceful shutdown)
CMD ["start-kafka.sh"]
```

Dockerfile Source: `https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/dockerfile`

Comment: This is not a docker-compose file and it doesn't get recognized. It's a file to build an image. [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<block mapping start>'' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983938/what-does-yaml-parser-parsererror-expected-document-start-but-found-blo)